# Align rasters with Python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, osgeo

I am trying to compare two rasters that overlap in a region but the comparison needs to be done in the whole raster. They don't have a common point but the pixel sizes are not that different. The thing that I have about GDAL Wrap but I cannot something about the target aligned pixels option.

Edit:

[Data-Tiff](https://we.tl/t-GzDGaFqHuD)

I want to align the 2 rasters that overlap an area in order to compare each pixel using DataFrame. The problem is that they don't have a common starting point and resolution and thus when I transform the raster to dataframe the points are not the same

I am adding also a code that I wrote:

```py
def align(raster, alignraster, how=np.ma.mean):
    
    ndv1, xsize1, ysize1, geot1, projection1, datatype1 = get_geo_info(raster)
    ndv2, xsize2, ysize2, geot2, projection2, datatype2 = get_geo_info(alignraster)
    
    geot1, geot2 = np.array(geot1), np.array(geot2)
    
    raster_sourceds = gdal.Open(raster, GA_ReadOnly)
    alignraster_sourceds = gdal.Open(alignraster, GA_ReadOnly)
    
    mraster = gdalnumeric.LoadFile(raster)
    mraster = np.ma.masked_array(mraster, mask=mraster == ndv1, fill_value=ndv1)
    
    nraster = gdalnumeric.LoadFile(alignraster)
    nraster = np.ma.masked_array(nraster, mask=nraster == ndv2, fill_value=ndv2)
    
    if geot1[1] >= geot2[1]:
        x_res = geot2[1]
        y_res = geot2[-1]
        col, row = alignraster_sourceds.RasterXSize, alignraster_sourceds.RasterYSize
        x_ref = np.arange(geot2[0], geot2[0] + col*geot2[1], geot2[1])
        y_ref = np.arange(geot2[3] + row*geot2[-1], geot2[3], -geot2[-1])
    
        t_x, t_y = geot1[0], geot1[3]
    
        dif_x = np.absolute(x_ref - t_x)
        dif_y = np.absolute(y_ref - t_y)
        common_x = x_ref[np.where(dif_x == np.min(dif_x))[0]]
        common_y = y_ref[np.where(dif_y == np.min(dif_y))[0]]
        
        if round(np.min(dif_x)/geot2[1])>1:
            #resample
            fraction = geot1[1]/geot2[1]
            mraster = zoom(mraster, [1,1+fraction], mode='nearest', order = 0)
            
            geot1[0] = common_x
            
        else:
            
            geot1[0] = common_x
    
            
        if round(np.min(dif_y)/geot2[-1])>1:
            #resample
            fraction = geot1[-1]/geot2[-1]
            mraster = zoom(mraster, [1+fraction, 1], mode='nearest', order = 0)
            
            geot1[3] = common_y
            
        else:
            
            geot1[3] = common_y
    
        geot1[1], geot1[5] = x_res, y_res
        mraster = np.ma.masked_array(mraster, mask=True, fill_value = -999999.0)
    
    else:
        x_res = geot1[1]
        y_res = geot1[-1]
        col, row = raster_sourceds.RasterXSize, raster_sourceds.RasterYSize
        x_ref = np.arange(geot1[0], geot1[0] + col*geot1[1], geot1[1])
        y_ref = np.arange(geot1[3] + row*geot1[-1], geot1[3], -geot1[-1])
    
        t_x, t_y = geot2[0], geot2[3]
    
        dif_x = x_ref - t_x
        dif_y = y_ref - t_y
    
        
        common_x = x_ref[np.where(dif_x == np.min(dif_x))[0]]
        common_y = y_ref[np.where(dif_y == np.min(dif_y))[0]]
        
        if round(np.min(dif_x)/geot1[1])>1:
            #resample
            fraction = geot2[1]/geot1[1]
            nraster = zoom(nraster, [1,1+fraction], mode='nearest', order = 0)
            geot2[0] = common_x
            
        else:
            
            geot2[0] = common_x
    
            
        if round(np.min(dif_y)/geot1[-1])>1:
            #resample
            fraction = geot2[-1]/geot1[-1]
            nraster = zoom(nraster, [1+fraction, 1], mode='nearest', order = 0)
            
            geot2[3] = common_y
            
        else:
            geot2[3] = common_y
    
        geot2[1], geot2[5] = x_res, y_res
        nraster = np.ma.masked_array(nraster, mask=True, fill_value = -999999.0)
    
    return mraster, nraster, geot1, geot2
```

Comment: I don't get it, Can you share more information? like image, etc...

Comment: Raster data has some inherent sway, but you really need to provide extent and pixel dimensions for each dataset to get any assistance.

Comment: @Helios I posted and update

Comment: @Vince I added a function with which I am trying to

Comment: The code is less useful than the actual coordinate values.

Comment: @Vince i added the 2 tiffs in the link to download

Comment: @Helios data added

Comment: The data is less useful than the actual coordinate values (no one should have to download your data to answer this question).